# Istream input checking

Tags: c++

I have function, which recieves coeffecents of polynomial via istream input. Im struggling with implementing this piece of code into it (can't fully understand how istream& works), so i can shield it from incorrect input. :

```
while (!std::cin.good())
{
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::cout << "error";
    std::cin >> A;
}
```

Into the function itself:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, Polynom& c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= c.degree; i++)
       s >> c.coefficents[i];

    return s;
}
```

Needless to say, that's how it is implemented in main()

```
std::cin >> A;
```

Polynom class:

```
class Polynom
{
     private:
     int degree;
     double* coefficents;

public:
   Polynom();
   Polynom(int size);
   Polynom(const Polynom&);
   ~Polynom();

   int get_degree();
   double get_coefficents(int);

   Polynom operator+(const Polynom&);
   Polynom operator-(const Polynom&);
   Polynom operator*(double p);
   void operator=(const Polynom&);

   friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& s, const Polynom& c);
   friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& s, Polynom& c);

   double& operator()(int i)
   {
       return coefficents[i];
   }
};
```

Any hints or optimal solutions are welcomed :)

Comment: please update your answer with Polynom definition

Comment: Totally unrelated to your question, but whenever I see a loop condition like `i <= c.degree` it makes me cringe. Do the "array" or "vector" (or whatever the container type might be) `c.coefficents` have `c.degree + 1` elements in it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes a polynom as degree+1 coefficients

Comment: As for your problem, why not create a function like `int get_int(std::string prompt)` which does the input-validation loop, and then you can simply call that when you need an `int`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, you may show your idea by posting an answer - maybe that's the solution

Comment: "_ Im struggling_" is not a problem description. What specifically have you tried, and what specific problems do you face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding my comment to an answer, it's possible to make a function which takes the stream  and uses the read-validation loop inside it to get the value.

Then in your `operator>>` overload you call this function to get each value.

Perhaps something like this:

```
template<typename T>
bool get_value(std::istream& input, T& value)
{
    while (!(input >> value))
    {
        // If end of file, don't attempt any more validation
        if (input.eof())
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Clear the error
        input.clear();

        // Ignore the rest of the line
        input.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    // When the loop ends, we have successfully read a value from the stream
    // Return true to tell that
    return true;
}
```

You could use it as:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, Polynom& c)
{
    double value;

    for (int i = 0; i <= c.degree && get_value(s, value); i++)
        c.coefficents[i] = value;

    return s;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Im curious: is it possibe to get rid of template<typename T> in this particular solution?

Comment: @Seeker Of course (just temove that line, and change the type of `value`), but why? Now it can be used for many different types exactly the same way. And as template arguments can be deduced there's no need to specify it when calling the function.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much